# "undefined variable" error message in database form submission

Tags: php, html, database, forms, form-submit

I have built a submit form my website. The information entered into the form gets stored in a database, and the photo gets stored in a folder on a server, and a link the image is stored in the database.

I based my code off of an example I have from class that works perfectly. However, when the form loads I get the following message

> Notice: Undefined variable: Name in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Photo in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Bio in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: City in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: State in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Zipcode in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Genre in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Link in C:\HTML\mgertenbach\BAND\submitband.php on line 28

Nothing I've tried has been able to make the page work and I cannot figure out the issue with my code.

Thank You!

```
$dbc=mysql_connect('localhost', 'mgertenbach', 'mollyr');
mysql_select_db('mgertenbach', $dbc);

$problem = FALSE;
if (!empty($_POST['bandname']) && !empty($_POST['bandbio']) && !empty($_POST['bandcity']) && !empty($_POST['bandstate']) && !empty($_POST['bandzipcode']) && !empty($_POST['bandgenre']) && !empty($_POST['bandlink'])) {
    $Name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bandname']));
    $Bio = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bandbio']));
    $City = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bandcity']));
    $State = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bandstate']));
    $Zipcode = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bandzipcode']));
    $Genre = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bandgenre']));
    $Link = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bandlink']));
}else {
if (!$problem) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO band_information (Name, Photo, Bio, City, State, Zipcode, Genre, Link) 
            VALUES ('$Name', '$Photo', '$Bio', '$City', '$State', '$Zipcode', '$Genre', '$Link');";
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'], "C:\\HTML\\mgertenbach\\BAND\\photos\\{$_FILES['thefile']['name']}") && @mysql_query($query, $dbc)){
            print '<p>Thanks for submitting your band!</p>';
        } else {
            print '<p>Could not submit band because: <br/>' .
            mysql_error($dbc) . '</p>';
        }
    }
else {

?>
    
    <h3>Please fill out the following information.</h3>
    
    <form action="submitband.php" method="post">
        <fieldset><legend>Who Are You?</legend>
            <label>Band Name: <input type="text" id="bandname" name="bandname" size="10"/></label>
            <br/><br/>
            <label>Upload Photo*: <input type="file" id="bandphoto" name="bandphoto"/></label>
            <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*image must be a square file
            <br/><br/>
            <label>Enter a short bio: <br/><textarea id="bandbio" name="bandbio" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></label>
        </fieldset>
        <br/><br/> 
        <fieldset><legend>Where Are You From?</legend>
            <label>City: <input type="text" id="bandbio" name="bandcity" size="10"/></label>
            <br/><br/>
            <label>State: 
                <select id="bandstate" name="bandstate">
                        <option value=""> </option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select></label>  
            <br/><br/>
            <label>Zipcode: <input type="text" id="bandzipcode" name="bandzipcode" size="10"/></label>
        </fieldset>  
        <br/><br/>
        <fieldset><legend>What's Your Music Like?</legend>
            <label>Genre: 
                <select id="bandgenre" name="bandgenre">
                        <option value="country">Country</option>
                        <option value="electronic">Electronic</option>
                        <option value="folk">Folk</option>
                        <option value="indie">Indie</option>
                        <option value="punk">Punk</option>
                        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
                </select>
                </label>
            <br/><br/>
            <label>Share a link to where we can hear it: <input type="text" id="bandlink" name="bandlink" size="40"/></label>
        </fieldset>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>          
    </form>
<?php
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['blah']))...

Answer (score 0):

You're testing for the presence of various `$_POST` variables, and if you find them all you set some local variables against them.

If you **don't** find them all you go on to try and write the information to the database.

Look long and hard at how your `if...then...else` is supposed to work.

Side notes:

- `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated. Don't use them. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.
- You're using `trim(strip_tags())` as some form of sanitization. This is nowhere near good enough. You should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` (for mysql), or consider moving to prepared statements.

Comment: Or take the next step up from the real escape string and use https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_PHP_Filters